# replace array elements contains brackets with a charecter

Tags: javascript

i have an array like this
in array some elements contains `(3.5-inch) ,(4-inch),(4-inch 64-bit), (4-inch 64-bit),(64-bit)` like that

```
[
"iPhone - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad - Simulator - iOS 6.1","iPad - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 6.1","iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
""
]
```

i need to replace `-` inside the bracket as `#` like `(3.5#inch) ,(4#inch),(4#inch 64#bit), (4#inch 64#bit),(64#bit)`

how can i possible.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried so far so that it really helps you? Or at least what you have thought of as a solution.

Comment: Regular expressions are what you need, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
var arr = ["iPhone - Simulator - iOS 6.1", "iPhone - Simulator - iOS 7.1", "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1", "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1", "iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1", "iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1", "iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1", "iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1", "iPad - Simulator - iOS 6.1", "iPad - Simulator - iOS 7.1", "iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 6.1", "iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 7.1", "iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1", "iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1", ""];
console.log('before', arr);
var i = arr.length;
while (i--) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/(-)(inch)/g, '#$2').replace(/(-)(bit)/g, '#$2');
}
console.log('after', arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for all possible occurences of `-` inside brackets:

```
var data = [
"iPhone - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad - Simulator - iOS 6.1","iPad - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 6.1","iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
""
];

data = data.map(function(value) {
    // first find the brackets
    return value.replace(/\([^)]*\)/g, function(val) {
        // now replace all occurences of - with #
        return val.replace(/-/g, "#");
    });
});
```

Here is the **[jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/1h57ugd1/)**

Comment: In this line all occurences of the regular expression should be replaced with the return value of the given function. The regular expression could be read as such: at first there should be a open bracket (`\(`), after that all chars except of a closing bracket are possible (`[^)]*`) and in the end there must be a closing bracket (`\)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [
"iPhone - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad - Simulator - iOS 6.1","iPad - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 6.1","iPad Retina - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
"iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 6.1",
"iPad Retina (64-bit) - Simulator - iOS 7.1",
""
]

var new_list = list.map(function(item){
   return item.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, function(m){ 
      return m.replace(/-/g, "#") 
   });
});
```

Comment: this is wrong, he wants to replaces hyphens *inside* parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), as:

```
var replaced = your_arr.map(function(val) {
  return val.replace(/(-)(inch|bit)/, "#$2");
});
console.log(replaced);
```